# Copying a mysql database from localhost to remote server using mysqldump.exe

Tags: mysql, database-backups

I want to copy a mysql database from my local computer to a remote server.

I am trying to use the mysql dump command. All the examples on the internet suggest doing something like

The initial `mysql>` is just the prompt I get after logging in.

```
mysql> mysqldump -u user -p pass myDBName | NewDBName.out;
```

But when I do this I get `You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds ... to use near 'mysqldump -u user -p pass myDBName | NewDBName.out'`

Since I have already logged in do I need to use -u and -p? Not doing so gives me the same error. Can you see what is wrong?

Answer (score 2):

`mysqldump` is not an SQL statement that you execute inside a `mysql` session but a distinct binary that should be started from your OS shell.

The are a few ways to use this. One of them is to pipe the output of `mysqldump` to another MySQL instance:

```
echo CREATE DATABASE remote_db | mysql -h remote_host -u remote_user -premote_password
mysqldump -h source_host -u root -ppassword source_db | mysql -h remote_host -u remote_user -premote_password -D remote_db
```

Comment: Is `-ppassword` meant to be `-p password`?

Comment: @Ankur If you use the short option form (-p), you cannot have a space between the option and the password. [MySQL Manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/mysql-command-options.html#option_mysql_password)

Comment: Also... actually putting the password in the command line is not good practice because someone who logs in later under the same account (on Unix at least) can see the password in the command history.  If you use -p without specifying the password, you will be prompted to enter the password in a secure manner.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to what Alexandre said, you probably don't want to pipe (|) output to NewDBName.out, but rather redirect it there (>).

So from the Windows/Unix command line:

```
mysqldump -u user -p pass myDBName > NewDBName.out
```

Note that if you have large binary fields (e.g. BLOBS) in some columns you may need to set an additional option (I think it was --hex-blob, but there might have been another option too).  If that applies to you, add a comment and I'll research the setting.

Comment: Nah I don't have that situation, but I do have an access denied situation despite the fact that I login to this db with its user name and password quite regularly :(

Answer (score 2):

I have had to dump large sets of data recently. From what I have found on a 200Mb database with 10,000+ records in many of the tables is the following.  I used the linux 'time' command to get actual time.

12 minutes using:
mysqldump -u user -p pass myDBName > db-backups.sql

7 minutes to clone the database:
mysqldump -u user -p pass myDBName | mysql -u user -p pass cloneDBName

And in less than a second:
mysqlhotcopy -u user -p pass myDBName cloneDBName

The last one blew my mind, but you have to be logged in locally where the database server resides.  Personally I think this is much faster than remotely doing a dump, the you can compress the .sql file and transfer it manually.